# Вычислить xor от последовательности нескольких аргументов без цикла

Tags: python

Нужно написать программу на Python поразрядного xor для нескольких аргументов.
Через `for` получилось почти сразу, но идей, как обойтись без него (используя функции `map`, `reduce` и прочее) нет:

```
n = int(input())
result = list(map(int, input().split()))
for i in range(n - 1):
    result = list(map(lambda a, b: a ^ b,
                      result,
                      list(map(int, input().split()))))
print(*result)
```

Comment: Может [`functools.reduce(lambda a, b: a ^ b, array)`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/functools.html#functools.reduce)

Comment: Пробовал так - не получилось: print(
    *map(
        lambda x: functools.reduce(
            lambda a, b: a ^ b,
            map(
                int,
                input().split()
            )
        ),
        range(int(input()))
    )
)

Comment: Зачем столько этих `map`, причём в одной строчке?) У вас есть три действия — ввод, получение xor'a (то есть одного числа, да?) и вывод. Ну так сделайте по строчке для каждого действия.

Comment: https://ideone.com/LJV59H

Comment: Мы получаем не число, а массив чисел (0 и 1).

Comment: А, ну тогда можно сначала всё-таки получить одно число, а потом преобразовать его в массив: 1) сначала в строку из нулей и единиц с помощью: `"{0:b}".format(число)` 2) затем в массив символов: `list(строка)` 3) затем в массив нулей и единиц: `list(map(int, массив_символов))`

Comment: Нет, мы вначале вводим число: количество слагаемых (n) хоr, потом сами слагаемые xor - массивы из 0 и 1, xor считается по индексам массивов (обрабатывается в result). Выводим массив, погоняйте выше указанную программу, она работает правильно, только нужно избавиться от цикла. То есть это поразрядный xor нескольких слагаемых.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Решение без циклов. Правда смысла делать без циклов я не вижу :(

```
from _operator import xor
from functools import reduce

# количество чисел
n = int(input())

# массив из `n` строк
lines = map(lambda _: input(), range(n))
# массив из `n` чисел, каждое число это массив из нулей и единиц
numbers = map(lambda line: map(int, line.split()), lines)
# xor чисел, то есть массив из нулей и единиц
# самое интересное здесь это поэлементный xor двух массив
# делается так: map(xor, x, y)
# Ответ на enSO: https://stackoverflow.com/a/18713344/5812238
result = reduce(lambda x, y: map(xor, x, y), numbers)
# выводим xor
print(*result)
```

Comment: Благодарю! Теперь буду разбираться в коде :)

Answer (score 1):

```
# чтобы не импортировать ничего "лишнего"
# lambda x, y: map(xor, x, y) можно заменить на:

lambda x, y:
        map(
            lambda a, b: a ^ b, 
            x,
            y
        )
```